# Ultrafast Lasers

Tags: optics, experimental-physics, laser, quantum-optics

Is the main idea of femtosecond or attosecond lasers is to achieve the high energy or do we have any other parameters achieved by ultra-fast lasers ?

Answer (score 3):

Femtosecond lasers, especially those with short pulse times, are spectrally very broad.  While for some applications this is a nuisance, it can also be turned into an advantage using [temporal and spectral focusing](http://helios.augustana.edu/~jvh/publications/OPEX_2005_temporal_focus.pdf) [PDF].

Comment: another nice temporal focusing ref: http://www.weizmann.ac.il/home/feyaron/PDFfiles/scanningless.pdf

Answer (score 1):

I would say high energy is not the most important advantage of short-pulse lasers (longer-pulse lasers typically have higher energy), achieving high power, high field, and high time resolution is typically the rationale for short-pulse lasers.